# Thunderstorm killed my router power supply

Tags: electric-shock

During a thunderstorm I heard a loud PAF with a light from where all the computer wires are. The router (a D-Link DIR-615) doesn't work any more, I suppose its power supply is out of order. Not sure about the router itself.

Is it likely that only the power supply is gone ? Is t here a way to get some power supply from another device but with the same specs and plug it into the router ?

Comment: You could probably buy a DC transformer and use that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to get a power supply with the same specifications, that means, same voltage, at least the same power in mA, and you should be good to go. Usually, these are pretty cheap.

Chances are though that your router itself was damaged due to electricity spikes. I wouldn't be surprised if the device itself doesn't work – even after changing the power supply.

Answer (score 1):

Things to know when selecting a DC power supply replacement.

1. Polarity.  This is generally shown by a circle in a circle icon on the power supply, this is important, if you get it wrong you can damage your electronics.  (If they're not already fried.)
2. Voltage.  This needs to be as close as possible.  Within a 5-10% is normally a good rule of thumb, but the closer the better.  Exact if possible.  If it's too far off it can damage your router.
3. Amperage.  This needs to be at least the same or higher.  This is a rated capacity, not a declaration of how much energy is going through, so it's perfectly fine to use a 2 Amp rated power supply on a 300mA device.

As far as your router, it's probably toast.  You can take a sniff, and if you smell magic smoke it's as good as done for, probably.